# ServiceBus error connecting to cluster SQL

Tags: sql-server, servicebus

we have Service Bus newly installed in our enviornment. We do have errors below where we see SQL connection timed out. When we check on the SQL server, we don't see any failover or errors.

.NET 4.6.2 and TLS 1.0 is installed & enabled on both Service bus and SQL.

1) What's the configuration for Service Bus retries interval time and number of retries ?

2) Anyone had a similar issue ?

```
TrackingId: 6851d220-9a45-47ed-aa0e-af65883a1999_BAE-MAS-0031, SubsystemId: NoSystemTracker. A SQL exception was caught. Command = [dbo].[PingDatabase], error number = -2, procedure = , server = RSBDB.domain.local\I1, databasename = RSBMessageContainer01, error = error number = -2, error state = 0, error class = 11, error message = Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.  This could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in time.  This failure occured while attempting to connect to the Principle server.  The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=23536; handshake=29996; , procedure = , line number = 0
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.  This could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in time.  This failure occured while attempting to connect to the Principle server.  The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=23536; handshake=29996;  ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.Cloud.ServiceBus.Common.Sql.SqlCommandAsyncResult.<GetAsyncSteps>d__5.MoveNext()
ClientConnectionId:d58f3d93-e749-4534-af8a-82884d7faaa6
Error Number:-2,State:0,Class:11
```

.

Comment: Are you sure there was not a "failover"?  In my testing, I've seen "hiccups" when the failover occurs.  Aka, it doesn't work gracefully, like when a computing-node for service bus goes down.  Can you try a failover-partner?  See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spike/2010/12/08/clarification-on-the-failover-partner-in-the-connectionstring-in-database-mirror-setup/